# How to select Chrome extensions to enable when using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, webdriver, web-testing

I am using Selenium web driver to develop an automated test using Chrome as my browser. I am using Python for this.

I have an extension on my Chrome browser that I would like enabled when Selenium opens Chrome. The problem is that when Selenium opens Chrome all the extensions are disabled by default.

How do I enable all or a certain extension on the Chrome browser when Selenium runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `ChromeOptions` class or `DesiredCapabilities`. For that you have to have the `.crx` file and load that with driver instance.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Code taken from @alecxe answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python) and more details about ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)