# Selenium :: Python :: Chrome Extension

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to load a `google chrome extension` with `Selenium WebDriver`.

But I receive an error `OSError: Path to the extension doesn't exist`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from os import path

path = "path to chrome driver"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx') # ALTERNATIVE 0
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

After reading various similar questions on this site I tried the following two alternatives:

```
# Alternative 1
chrome_options.add_extension('~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/[Extension ID]/Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx')

#Alternative 2
chrome_options.add_extension(path.abspath("Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx"))
```

But none of them work. Alternative 1 gives same error message as the original code whereas Alternative 2 gives error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'abspath'`

Does anyone have a clue what I could be doing differently?

Comment: Have you tried `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)` ?  It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this is what I am doing in the last line of the code...isn't it?

Comment: No, you're including a path.  You're also importing path and then overwriting it.

Comment: Ok, understand what you mean. Tried this out but I do get the same error message `OSError: Path to the extension doesn't exist`

Comment: Have you installed the webdriver for Chrome?  You can find it here. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Yes, I have installed it and refer to it using path. Webdriver works just fine. Only adding the extension doesn't work because apparently I am pointing to the wrong directory / path. But not able to find the correct path. Already tried to copy the extension folder to the same folder where webdriver is placed. This also doesn't work....any other idea?

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141847/how-to-select-chrome-extensions-to-enable-when-using-selenium?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried exactly this before and it doesn't work. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More thank likely, this is because python is referencing the wrong path with what would normally be the home directory shortcut of `~/` in the path. Python will try and run the file from the current directory, so for example if your code is in `~/Dev/testproject`, and the code being called above is really trying to run `/home/username/Dev/testproject/~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/[Extension ID]/Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx`

Try using the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os

chromedriver = "path to chrome driver"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


# choose one of the following 2:
chrome_options.add_extension(os.path.expanduser('~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/[Extension ID]/Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx'))  # Option 1: if your extension is not also in your project folder
chrome_options.add_extension(os.path.abspath('Adblock-Plus_v1.12.4_0.crx'))  # Option 2: if your extension IS in your project folder


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

EDIT: avoid declaring a variable named `path` since you are importing `path` from `os`. This is why you are getting the error on Alternative #2.

Comment: Thanks, crookedleaf. It is working now. Regarding `path`....could have seen this myself. Sometimes I just don't see the obvious when debugging ;-)