# Unable to run Chrome selenium " unknown error: cannot process extension #1"

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to run a chrome selenium driver and add an extention:

```
manifest_json = """..... """
background_js = """...."""
ext_file = 'my_extention.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(ext_file, 'w') as zp:
    zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
    zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_extension(ext_file)
d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=co)
```

That throws an error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: invalid public key length
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.19.0-39-generic x86_64)
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumble on that issue when I was trying to base64 encode a .crx in order to have the extension running on selenium (that was in the context of protractor tests).

I suspect this is due to the extension not being empacted with the same browser than the one trying to run it.

Anyway I end up giving-up and just I just added an option to chromium to load the un-empacted extension:

`--load-extension=path_to_the_extension_folder`

I hope it helps.

Comment: This error happened to me when I moved my *.zip chrome extensions from one machine to another. I ended up with your solution; --load-extension, which is much nicer anyways.

Comment: can you please tell me where you added this option?

Comment: if you run chrome/chromium using a command line it'll be `./chrome.exe --load-extension=path_to_the_extension_folder`