# 'Send Later' button not getting while automate the code by using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I add-on Boomerang for gmail to get Send later button on gmail compose, and when I go for automate that 'Send later' button on selenium I am not getting that button can anybody please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Source [Using Extensions with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

With selenium you have a standard profile in your browser,for chrome it is like I post in top. 
For firefox:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 0)
Driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```