# How record the screen while Selenium Python is running (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, opencv

I have Selenium code running, if the test fail i want to see the entire process from start to finish (not using a screenshot), something know how can record the screen while selenium running.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


# If test is fail i want to save video file who recorded the whole process
def test1():
    driver.get(...)
    e = driver.find_element(...)
    e.click()
    assert e.text == 'Some Text'
```

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Use an external library such as ffmpeg
For example:

```
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'gdigrab', '-framerate', '15', '-offset_x', '0', '-offset_y', '0', '-video_size', '1920x1080', '-i', 'desktop', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-vprofile', 'baseline', '-g', '15', '-crf', '1', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-threads', '4', 'output.mkv'])
# Start selenium code...
time.sleep(10)
proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem

I have 3 ideas:

1. using ffmpeg as above
2. using chrome extension, u must create crx file of extension by some ways, example at https://crxextractor.com/, then `.add_extension` read more in [Using Extensions with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python)
3. using selenium to open new tab to https://recordscreen.io/

I will take more infomation after