# While executing Selenium script in Chrome browser getting failed to load extension error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing selenium script in Chrome browser, during this am getting Manifest file is missing or unreadable error.

Attaching the error screenshot. Please help me here.

[Chrome Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxpG2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load an extension (i.e., like you would typically load a folder into chrome for testing), then it needs to be zipped for selenium. I ran into the same error when using the top answer on the cited source below `chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')`. Zipping the file worked for me.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51528329