# Is it possible to make a web scraper use a plugin (in Chrome's extension bar)?

Tags: python, plugins, web-scraping, automation, web-crawler

TO be specific, I want to make a Python web crawler that uses a plugin on Chrome called "Adapt Prospector," which allows you to find people's emails once you land on their linkedin page. Here is an example of what I mean:

https://i.postimg.cc/DyxWzxWJ/example_pic.png

You first go on the person's linkedin page, then click the plugin logo on Chrome's extension bar, then the plugin will show you the linkedin profile's email (if there is one).

Basically, I want to create a program that goes to a person's linkedin page, then clicks the plugin logo on the extension bar, then scrapes the data the plugin is showing.

I definitely know how to do the first part, but I'm not sure if the last 2 parts are possible. I searched extensively on if its possible to make a web scraper that uses a plugin, but I haven't found any "yes" or "no" answers to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to :

- Find which request gives the informations you need using the Network tab of your browser console. Then do the same request with your favorite python library
- Use selenium which will behave more or less like your browser, go to the person's linkedin page, and the informations should be somewhere in the page, maybe hidden.

Your plugin just reorganize the informations it finds on the page. Linkedin provides to your browser all the informations you need.

EDIT : [Using Extensions with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python) you can try this but I think that selenium without the extension will do fine as well