# Run a chrome extension with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a question:

Is there any way to run a chrome extension with javascript? My idea is to create a code that receives a link and automatically executes a chrome extension that what it does is detect a Vimeo video and download it ... My intention is to stop doing the manual process of downloading video by video because I want to download several ... that's why I want to know first if I can run a chrome extension with javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Chrome extensions are build in Javascript. You can use content script that runs only for vimeo. Put your logic in the content script.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking to trigger an existing 3rd-party extension with JS? Then the likely answer is no..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be able to do this without specifically `javascript`. If you're okay with using `python`, you can use the `selenium` package, which allows you to load Chrome options and extensions. [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python)