# How to use Addons in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed an addon in Firefox with Selenium. I need to use it but I don't know how. Without Selenium, in a normal browser, I can use it by clicking on the icon. I also use a preset profile where the addon is activated but when I open the browser using selenium, it is deactivated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Extensions with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python)

Comment: Thank you, No, it doesn't. I know how to install addons, I don't know ho to use them