# Windows Task Scheduler & Selenium run issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-task-scheduler

I am using Selenium to do some key clicking to choose a specific VPN from the VeePn Extension for Chrome.
Everything works fine when I run the Python script manually, because it opens up the browser.
But when I try to runt he same script through the Windows task scheduler, because it does not open the browser, it appears the key clicks are not being recognised, which I presume is because it is a headless browser?

So my question is, is there anyway to force the browser to open when the script is activated through task scheduler? Or is there a better solution to enabling and selecting a specific VPN from the extension?

Currently I have programmed in the screen co-ordinates of where I want to click the mouse, after maximising the browser window. Yes I realise not the best solution .

Thanks

I tried opening the Chrome browser independently and in a non headless mode, plus checked the search engines, but they all refer to the navigating a web page, opposed to controls on the web browser
Have checked that I have the latest chrome-driver installed

Comment: By Task Manager, do you mean Task Scheduler?

Comment: Yes, and I have updated my question to show that now, sorry about that

Comment: Have you tried to use pyautogui?

Comment: I have not, but I will investigate that, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You can look at this as a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python)